# GS025 error when executing Gnosis Safe multisig transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I'm having problems with executing a multisig transaction on a 2/2 Gnosis Safe. I've successfully executed single sig transactions on a different vault, but I can't get multisig to work:

- After signing the same `safeTransaction` on chain, the `safe.getOwnersWhoApprovedTx(safeTxHash)` function returns the 2 addresses of the owners who approved the transaction using `safe.approveTransactionHash(safeTxHash)`. The signatures seem to be committed properly
- When running `safe.executeTransaction` I get the error `GS025`. Example transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xf99d48936b4875a586a8ba32549cc677a7317658a50bd7a5c57a7f9dcdca4214
- Network: Rinkeby

Here's the full code:

```
const safeTransaction = await safeForTheFirstSigner.createTransaction({
  to: toAddress,
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther(String(amount)).toString(),
  data: toAddress,
  nonce: 17,
});

const safeTxHash = await safeForTheFirstSigner.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
// Note: this returns the 2 owners after approving the tx, so the approval part definitively works
const approvers = await safeForTheFirstSigner.getOwnersWhoApprovedTx(safeTxHash);

await safeForTheFirstSigner.approveTransactionHash(safeTxHash);
await response.transactionResponse?.wait();

const executeTxResponse = await safeForTheSecondSigner.executeTransaction(safeTransaction);
await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();
```

In `GnosisSafe.sol` this line is throwing the error:

```
require(msg.sender == currentOwner || approvedHashes[currentOwner][dataHash] != 0, "GS025");
```

https://github.dev/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/1448705d9cee77c912ff808ad9d9b77491ab4182/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L291

I'm stuck on how to debug further from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is a shortcoming in the Safe core sdk (maybe worth opening an issues).

You create a transaction with nonce `17` and also approve this transaction. But the `executeTransaction` function doesn't check if this is the current nonce of the Safe. The issue here is, that the Safe contracts enforce the order of transaction by nonce (similar to a normal Ethereum account). Therefore in the `executeTransaction` contract method it uses the current nonce (which was for the mentioned Safe `1` at the point of writing), but the `approveTransactionHash` was based on a transaction hash that uses nonce `17`.

A simple fix is to **not** specify the nonce, then the sdk will automatically retrieve the correct nonce.

Note: `GS025` stands for `Hash has not been approved`. You can see all error codes in the [safe-contracts repo](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/docs/error_codes.md).